# remember me functionality in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have implemented remember me functionality as this question

[How to create "remember me checkbox" using Codeigniter session library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984313/how-to-create-remember-me-checkbox-using-codeigniter-session-library)

first answer.
I created a cookie with a random number code as value and it stored in db(user table). On login, db code checks with cookie value.It works fine on my localhost server. But in live server which has a subdomain url has problem.Also I tested it with another server with ip address as url. There also it is not working. In both cases cookie created but cant read the cookie. Please help me.

cookie set by

```
$auto_login_hash_code = uniqid();
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$cookie = array(
            'name' => 'rememberMe',
            'value' => $auto_login_hash_code,
            'expire' => 31536000,
            'domain' => $domain,
            'path' => '/'
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

and reading cookie by

```
    if (get_cookie('rememberMe')) {
$hashcode = $this->CI->input->cookie('rememberMe');
$this->CI->load->model('loginmodel', '', true);
$username = $this->CI->loginmodel->get_username_by_hashcode($hashcode);//in this function setting session variables
    }
```

Thanks in advance
iijb

Comment: would be helpful if you show your code...!

Comment: Have you tried prepending a period to the `domain` key of the cookie?

Comment: From what I believe you can't set a cookie with one domain and read it with another, if that's what you're trying to do ...

Comment: No the whole thing done in same server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting library for that on github.
search remember me on github, load it and just follow below steps.
Verify cookie if token is present in database go to home page

```
 $this->load->library('rememberme');  
            $cookie_user = $this->rememberme->verifyCookie();
            if ($cookie_user) 
            {
                $this->load->view('search_view');
            }

else
        {
            // If checkbox is checked it return true either false
            $checked = (isset($_POST['Checkbox1']))?true:false;  

            if($checked== true)

            {
                    //$this->load->view('tested');
                    $this->load->library('rememberme');  
                    $this->rememberme->setCookie($this->input->post('loginemil'));
                    //$this->rememberme->setCookie('set cookie here');

            }
else{
dont set anything
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this can be done by editing/extending system Session library.

**First:** In user login function add remember me check-

```
    if($remember)
    {
        $data['new_expiration'] = 60*60*24*30;//30 days
        $this->session->sess_expiration = $data['new_expiration'];
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

**Second:** Edit system Session library [I am not sure whether extending Session will work or not]
Go to this line in `sess_read()` method

```
if (($session['last_activity'] + $this->sess_expiration) < $this->now)
```

Before that line add following code

```
if(isset($session['new_expiration'])){
   $this->sess_expiration = $session['new_expiration'];
}
```

This works fine for me.