# Codeigniter storing sessions in database

Tags: database, codeigniter, session, frameworks

I am having trouble storing sessions in database with codeigniter.

When a user logs in, a session is created and stored in the database. The data is filled in the database. When a user uses the logout button, the session data is emptied, however, the session still exists in the database.

The problem is when a user doesn't use the logout button but just closes the webbrowser. The session data is not emptied, but the user is still logged out. (i hava set this in my config file) The session should be destroyed in the database but it is not!

When a user logs back in after having clicked the 'logout' button, the session that has been created the first time the user logged in, is filled again with the data. So no problems with this.

But when a user logs back in after having closed the browser, it creates a new session.

This problem ends up in having endless sessions, sessions are being created every time a user closes the browser.

something else that confuses me: when I log in with an account, a session is created. When I then logout with that account and log in with another account, the session is stored in the same record as the other account. When are new records in the session table created?

I am using version 2.1.3 of codeigniter.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//Session config:

$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter?

Comment: version 2.1.3 of codeigniter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `sess_expire_on_close` set to `TRUE`, so this is expected behavior, and you *usually* want that in most circumstances. The issue is, a new cookie (hence session) is generated when the browser is closed and opened again. From the [CI session class documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) (go to the bottom where it talks about saving sessions in a db):

> Note: The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to do it.

So, it's not something you have to worry about addressing, orphaned sessions will be automatically garbage collected from the DB by the session class. If you want, you can implement code to clean it out via cron, but you really don't need to.

Now, if this presents a problem for *specific* logged in users (e.g. 'remember me') *but* you want the session to expire on close for everyone else, you can work around it by manually setting another cookie that far outlasts your session cookie and correlate an item in it within your session DB. This allows you to figure out who the user 'was' and reconstruct the session if it should magically persist for them. There's a bit more about that [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3988774/50049) to a somewhat related question.