# codeigniter: how to retrieve the cookie value with its name

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am trying to get the cookie value by its name. This is the first time i am using the cookie in codeigniter .

Here is how  i am trying to get the cookie value which i have set, but its show output in my view page as `bool(false)`

How i am setting cookie into my controller....

```
 $ranum=random_string('alnum', 20);//generates random numbers/strings  
   $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'remember_me_token',
        'value'  =>$ranum,
        'expire' => '1209600',  // Two weeks
        'domain' => base_url(),  //my base url is http://localhost
        'path'   => '/'
    ); 
    set_cookie($cookie);
```

How i am trying trying to get my cookie value is

```
<?php echo $this->input->cookie('remember_me_token', TRUE);  //giving output like bool(false)  ?>
```

Note: i am using ajax  when users click the "submit" button

Please help me how to check if cookie is available with this name, if its available then how to retrieve its value into my view page..

Update:
I checked my browser cookies,its looking like this...its seems i have problem in setting cookie. If so then please help me why my cookie is not setting?

[image]

Comment: Try setting domain to / like `domain' => '/',`

Comment: @Raidenace Sorry, Same problem still

Comment: @Raidenace i updated my question. Please check it once. It seems cookie is not setting.. Why? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cookie is not available on the same request/page where you set it. Once you set a cookie it must be sent to browse.

From PHP.NET

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter.

**Update:**

Base url should be something like `yourdomain.com`. Check the `$config['base_url']` in your `config.php` file. You can't use `$config['base_url']=http://localhost/`, you should set it as `http://localhost/yourdomain/` or keep it blank.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
```

Comment: i updated my question. Please check it once. It seems cookie is not setting.. Why? Please help

Comment: Then how i solve this problem. I am try to implement this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984313/how-to-create-remember-me-checkbox-using-codeigniter-session-library  into my project , so i need to view my cookie value.  Please help me

Comment: What is the name of your `domain/folder` where the project saved in your disk, the root folder is `yourdomain`.

Comment: inside htdocs  i.e `xampp/htdocs/my_project_all_folder_contents`

Comment: your new update helped me.. i kept my base_url blank, & setting cookie like `'domain' => '',
            'path'   => '/'`  .Now its showing value like `string(20) "YPiB3eNGJPFhinRshzVs"`

Comment: So you should set it `$config['base_url']='http://localhost/my_project_all_folder_contents'` or keep it blank.

Comment: my_project_all_folder_contents is not the folder name. I mean its all files. I kept all my codeigniter file into htdocs

Comment: No, you should keep them in a folder and this folder (i.e. myproject) is your domain, so when you will type `localhost/myproject` it'll show the site. You can keep multiple site/project in the `htdocs` folder using sub folders in the `htdocs` folder, each sub folder in the `htdocs` will be your project's domain.

Comment: Yeash previously i was doing like that only but later i found that i have to keep http:www.mysite.com/site/..   ,i have to keep extra folder name after my domain... Problem here : http://www.thebestbookfinder.com/ . in my all view page its coming under /site/  i am not able to view with its direct domain name.